# Close the case workspace tab from chatter publisher

Tags: chatter, publisher-action

On case record, we have used Chatter publisher to create layouts transferring the case to another group or a user. After you transfer a case to a different employee, users would like to close the workspace tab when they are in the chatter publisher layout

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is console navigation.

1. If you are using a quick action custom aura lightning component for transferring the case. Then you can use lightning:workspace API in your component code. use getEnclosingTabId() Method to know current tab Id and closeTab({tabId}) Method to close the current Tab.
2. If you are using a standard quick action layout. You can include a hidden lightning component (with no UI) inside your case lightning record page. This component should use **force:recordData** & recordUpdated event. to identify the case owner field Change. If there is any change in ownership from the current running User to different user/queues. Then you can use lightning:workspace API in your component code. use getEnclosingTabId() Method to know current tab Id and closeTab({tabId}) Method to close the current Tab.